# OpenCV reading and instantly writing writes a different image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm going crazy with this problem and I can't understand what might be going on.

I've a small c++ script using OpenCV to play around with images, and I can't figure out this behaviour.

```
imwrite("/Users/myuser/read.jpg", imread("/Users/myuser/write.jpg");
```

if I then run `diff /Users/myuser/read.jpg /Users/myuser/write.jpg` on the terminal I get `Binary files ageval.jpg and 1.jpg differ`.

I'd like to understand why might this be going on and how could I possibly solve it so the image is exactly the same?

Thank you!

Comment: jpg is a lossy compression scheme.  Every load/save cycle will change the image.

Comment: Makes sense! can you recommend another compression scheme where I have less chances of this happening?

Comment: The only way you're going to be able to load and save the exact same image is with an uncompressed format, like tga, bmp, or tiff.  Even though png is lossless you're not guaranteed that the compressed image will be the same after a load/save cycle because the compression might be a different level or a different library giving a slightly different result.

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much!

Comment: you can use png. i am not agree with "Even though png is lossless you're not guaranteed that the compressed image will be the same after a load/save cycle because the compression might be a different level or a different library giving a slightly different result.."